# How can I initialise a class with a declared variable inside a function?

Tags: javascript, function, class

I have never coded before in my life and in my second semester of Engineering, in university finesse have been given the full immersion of JavaScript. This might sound rather amateur but I want to know how to initialise a class with a declared variable inside a function.
The "Deck" class has all been precoded for me. I have to retrieve and parse a JSON string which I have coded into a variable called `deckObject` (which I have also done). Now I have to use that variable to initialise the Deck class.

```
function retrieveDeck()
{
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined")
    {
        // TODO: Retrieve the stored JSON string and parse
        //       to a variable called deckObject.

        var deckObject = JSON.parse(deckInstance);

        //       Use this to initialise an new instance of
        //       the Deck class.

    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Error: localStorage is not supported by current browser.");
    }

}
```

Comment: Check out the constructor of the `Desk` class. It should tell you what parameters it requires to be instantiated.

Comment: The terminology used is a bit weird without knowing what string deckInstance is. Is the answer really as simple as `var deckInstance = new deckObject();` ? Or `var deckInstance = new Deck( deckObject );` ?

Comment: You'll need to have a look at what the `Deck` class contains, specifically the constructor and what you need to pass it, once you've done that you can do `var deck = new Deck(p1,p2....)`

Comment: One of @Shilly's answers is probably what you're looking for. If not, could you add `console.log(deckInstance);` on the line above the line with `JSON.parse` and post in your question what gets logged in the console? It'd help a lot to know what `deckInstance` is exactly.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of info there. It's basically a program which creates a typical deck of cards, shuffles it and then displays it. After the click of a button it converts the deck instance into a JSON string and stores it. When another button is clicked the program retrieves JSON string, parses it and then initialises the deck class to display the entire deck once again. The snippet of code I showed here is the function which retrieves the JSON.